# Parsing Large Numbers

Tags: python

I am writing some simple code to raise a base value to a power
then perform some operations on the output.

I have included the code I am using now, below ( see end of this message ), also see immediately below what this looks like when I run my script from the console :

```
.........................................
C:\PYTHON34>python tst.py
INPUT Value: 431.1
INPUT Power Value; 1.9907
RESULT  1739.554505641426658257842063903808593750000000000000000000000000
.........................................
```

This is the code I am currently using :

```py
import time
e0=time.time()
c0=time.clock()

import sys
import math
from sympy import mpmath
from mpmath import *
mpmath.mp.dps = 10000


inputx = float(input('Enter inputx Value: '))
powerx =float(input('Enter Power Value; '))

inputx_squared = float((mpmath.power(inputx, powerx)))%1999

print('\r')
print('RESULT ', '%.60f' % inputx_squared)

elapsed_time=time.time() -e0
cpu_time=time.clock() -c0

print('\r')
print("CPU TIME ;", cpu_time)
```

What I need to be able to do ;

1.) Store whole number value to left of the decimal point without decimals to a variable = x

2.) Grab entire decimal value to the right of the decimal point and store in a variable = y

Parse (y) according to some simple rules. Here's where it gets trick for me.

What I want to do is examine (y) to see if there are any leading leading and trailing zeros

In the example ; "1739.554505....." IF this value was instead, something like any of the following ;

```
1739.0554505
1739.00554505
1739.000554505
```

Then I want to extract the whole number less any continuous leading zeroes

NEXT, I want to cut the number so that when there are four continuous trailing zeros, all zeros starting from the first one that started off the first four continuous zeros and all following zeroes are
truncated

So in our example ; 
"1739.554505641426658257842063903808593750000000000000000000000000"

(y) becomes "55450564142665825784206390380859375"

Next I want to take the mod of above value by %1999

This returns "1407"

Next I want to join this value AS the decimal value to the right as ;

1739.1407

Comment: I'm intrigued, what are you working on where you need such large numbers and precision, perhaps astronomy? What is the purpose of applying modulo 1999 to the mantissa, some kind of compression trick?  If you convert a float to an int it rounds down, effectively dropping the mantissa giving you the `1739` part. In Python, a string IS an iterable type, no need to convert it to an array. String `slicing` in Python is also pretty fast.

Comment: you can get the whole number with n = int(x)

Comment: As for the floating point stuff, I have concerns about your math, and I'm not touching that.

Comment: In order to get `1739.554505641426658257842063903808593750000000000000000000000000` , `%1999` has already been applied.  Then you want to apply `%1999` to `554505641426658257842063903808593750000000000000000000000000`.  So to be clear, you mean to apply `%1999` twice?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the first comment and would recommend using strings.

```
Result = 1739.554505641426658257842063903808593750000000000000000000000000
z = str(Result).split(".")
x = z[0]
y = z[1].strip("0")
mode = int(y)%1999
new_res = float(x+"."+str(mode))
print(new_res)
>>>1739.1407
```

The strip() method removes all leading and trailing zeros.
And I am also interested in the application of such operations.

Comment: Looks good, although I wonder about the comment in the question `when there are four continuous trailing zeros, all zeros starting from the first one that started off the first four continuous zeros and all following zeroes are truncated`, is that a long winded way of saying drop all trailing zeros, or only where there are 4 or more, and what to do if there are four zeros and then non zero values - perhaps they are not significant? It looks very much like grabbing the significand for scientific notation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) type:

```
import math
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext

getcontext().prec = 60
inputx = Decimal('431.1')
powerx = Decimal('1.9907')
inputx_squared = (inputx ** powerx) % 1999

x = math.floor(inputx_squared)
y = inputx_squared - x
```

which gives you

```
In: x
Out: 1739
In: y
Out: Decimal('0.554505641528269687606334953784096474037969748439285550')
```